# Move button in a ScrollView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I currently have a view and within it I have a scrollView. On that scrollView I have a button and a UITableView.

Given some condition, I want to move those two things up. I am currently doing this:

```
    tempFrame = [addressTableView frame];
    tempFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
    tempFrame.origin.y = 2.0;
    tempFrame.size.width = 320.0;
    tempFrame.size.height = 103.0;
    [addressTableView setFrame:tempFrame];        
   // [self.scrollView addSubview:self.addressTableView]; (does not do anything)

    tempFrame = [buttonContinue frame];
    tempFrame.origin.x = 20.0;
    tempFrame.origin.y = 40.0;
    tempFrame.size.width = 150.0;
    tempFrame.size.height = 25.0;
    [buttonContinue setFrame:tempFrame];
   // [self.scrollView addSubview:self.buttonContinue]; (does not do anything)
```

This method works fine on views with no scrollView.

Any tips on how to correctly move objects in a scrollView would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just moving them, rather than resizing, try moving the button with a CGAffineTransform. (You could also resize, by concatenating a CGscale and CGtranslate).

So for your button, it would be something very close to:

```
buttonContinue.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(20,40);
```

This would move your button 20pixels to the right and 40 pixels down.

To move it back later simply call:

```
buttonContinue.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Also, as an aside, you can create a new frame, using one line, rather the the four lines above like:

```
buttonContinue.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 150, 25);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this did not work. I tried both methods. I think it might have something to do with the fact that this button and the table view is on a scrollView, which is inside a 'View'. But note, that the 'Referencing Outlets' for both of these is the File's Owner.

Comment: Are your buttons hooked up to their IBOutlets (and are those IBOutlets properties?)

Comment: Yes they are hooked up and they are also properties.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, I think you should uncheck "Autolayout" property in file inspector for this specific ViewController. I had same problem and by unchecking autolayout my problem was solved. May be this will help to solved out your problem.

Good Luck !!

Comment: Thanks for the response. This did work. But unchecking the autolayout messes up the scrollView screen. As in, it pushes everything to the top and off of the screen. Will I have to reset the size for the scrollView?

Comment: I think there is no other way so you have to reset everything :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
[addressTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,320,103)];        
[buttonContinue setFrame:CGRectMake(20,40,150,25)];
```

If that's not working then there is a problem on the reference for your elements *addressTableView* and *buttonContinue*. And if they aren't already inside your scrollview use

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:addressTableView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:buttonContinue];
```

Making sure your scrollView variable is linked with its element on IB.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to move button

```
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pointMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
-(IBAction) pointMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
  CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self]; //here you can give scrollview
  UIControl *control = sender;
  control.center = point;
}
```